# react native generate a loop on notification received

Tags: react-native

I have an issue, on my react native app when i manage remote notification, on opened app notification the alert with the content it is replicated many times like it is inside a loop.

Here the code that manage it, what wrong?

```
useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;
    if (mounted) {
      const getData = async () => {
        let deviceData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('device_data');
        deviceData = JSON.parse(deviceData);
        setDeviceName(deviceData.lastname);
        setDeviceUUID(deviceData.uuid);
      };
      getData();

      // mostra notifica quando app è aperta
      messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
        Alert.alert(
          remoteMessage.notification.title,
          remoteMessage.notification.body,
          [
            {
              text: 'Procedi',
              onPress: () => {
                navigation.navigate('Details', {
                  siteId: remoteMessage.data.site_id,
                });
              },
            },
          ],
          {cancelable: false},
        );
        // Alert.alert(
        //     remoteMessage.notification.title,
        //     remoteMessage.notification.body,
        // );
      });
    }
  }, [deviceName]);
```